# PHP 5.3.3 : Download file from server and continue script execution

Tags: php, readfile, php-5.3

I'm using this bit of code to download a file (`path_facture_name`) from the server to the client browser :

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path_facture_name) . '"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path_facture_name));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path_facture_name);
ob_end_flush();
# ----
# Some other PHP code
# ----
```

This works just fine, but when the file is downloaded, the script is ended, and the part `Some other PHP code` will never be executed.

So, my question is, is there a better way to download a file from the server that don't abort the execution of the next part of the code ?

I've tried to use `<iframe>` or `JavaScript` code to redirect the `window` to a sipparate `.php` file that will handle the download. But that didn't work because this feature that I wanna add is a part of an 18 years old complex `php` CRM that I can't easily/freely edit.

I'm looking for a `PHP` solution or guidelines.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using a version of PHP that old in production. It's downright dangerous.

Comment: is there any reason you can't do your other code _before_ you trigger the download? What tasks are you carrying out? Or perhaps it's something which can be carried out by some other process e.g. a script triggered by a cron job

Comment: @MatthewDaly, My client is the kind of _Too busy to improve_ :(

Comment: @ADyson, the other PHP script will execute some `sql` queries and reload the current `php` page to display the new data.

Comment: off topic, please consider upgrading. http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: "and reload the current php page"...you can't do that, only the browser can do that in this situation. You've already given your response to the request in the form of a file download. The only way to "reload the current page" from the server would be to send some new HTML for the browser to display. But you can't respond to a single HTTP request with both a file download _and_ a HTML document. It's physically impossible. You've already set headers indicating to the browser that the response is a file for download.

Comment: Your best option, if you can, is to modify the way the page makes this request - use some JS to get it to trigger the download request in a separate window. Then meanwhile, again use JS to force the page itself to reload via a separate request - in that action you can run your SQL and return updated HTML, meanwhile, the download is happening separately.

Comment: "My client is the kind of Too busy to improve"...too busy to give any thought to the safety and security of their servers and their business-critical data then either, I guess. Oh dear. There ought to come a point where you refuse to offer support to them unless they permit an upgrade to take place. If they fall victim to a known security flaw in this PHP version, then they have no-one to blame but themselves...however I will bet a large sum they will blame you instead, since you're the IT guy...it's in your interest to get them moving, IMHO.

Comment: So this is a HTTP limitation. Thank  you @ADyson

Comment: Exactly. There's no such thing as a multi-part response. It would be great if there was, but it doesn't exist currently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer for this question is @**ADyson**'s comment above :

**«** *"and reload the current php page"...you can't do that, only the browser can do that in this situation. You've already given your response to the request in the form of a file download. The only way to "reload the current page" from the server would be to send some new HTML for the browser to display. But you can't respond to a single HTTP request with both a file download and a HTML document. It's physically impossible. You've already set headers indicating to the browser that the response is a file for download.* **»**

So this is a `HTTP` limitation. We can't do a multi-part response.

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting the form (or whatever takes you to the download page) use javascript to display sg. like "File downloading, press ok" and a button. It will stay because there's no HTML content to be loaded.
Set this button to load your download page again but skipping the file download headers this time (with a get switch).